# How to ensure correct type-checking in sequelize join-queries (with TypeScript)?

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

Suppose we have two tables A and B associated like this:

```
A.hasMany(B);
B.belongsTo(A);
```

And we have this join query:

```
async getAll(): Promise<B[]> {
    return B.findAll({
         include: {
            model: A,
            attributes: ['id'],
            required: true
         }
    });
}
```

TypeScript says the return type for `B.findAll()` is B,
but this function is returning the type `B & {"A": {id:number}}` which is not B.

How to handle the fact that for TypeScript's compiler the return type is the same for join-queries and single-table-queries when is not the same at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a little research I found [this](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/database-tools/evaluating-type-safety-in-the-top-8-typescript-orms#sequelize) article talking about TypeScript ORMs and type safety, and the conclusion is that maybe Sequelize is not the best option if type safety is a priority:

*[...] Furthermore, when fetching associations using include, the return type does not include information about the nested shape of the fetched data, and to properly compile without errors, the developer must use ! non-null assertions and rejectOnEmpty parameters to override the compiler.*